# Sequence numbering with xpages

Tags: javascript, forms, xpages, sequence, counter

I am working on a project with xpages.
I would like to create a counter that is incremented when I create a new document.
I have created a form that contains a field reference that is initialized to 1.How can i do to recover the first value of the first line which is therefore 1 and add 1 to get a sequence of numbers.I tried getfirstitem() but it does not work.
I also wish that every new year the counter restarts at 0.

Answer (score 4):

Sequence numbering is a little challenge once you want to run your application on more than one server or offline (just wait for it, it will happen to your application too). Having said that, there are a number of approaches taken over the years:

- Use @Subset(@DbColumn(@DbName,"SomeViewSortedDecendingByNumber",1),1) +1; Problem: if 2 users open a document and haven't saved it
- Use a `applicationScope` variable, that you increment just before saving (don't forget the `synchronized` keyword for that function). Problem: value only shows on save - or you get "holes" if users don't save a document.
- Use an agent that only runs on one server. This sorts out multi-server and offline use. Problem: number shows up much later than document creation
- Use a web service (written in Notes) that gives out the next available number. You face the same problems: "when to provide" (open or save the document), "what if user doesn't save, no offline use
- Don't store the number, but use the view's numbering mechanism to display a number

What exactly is your use case? Tell a little more!

Comment: My goal is to create customer tickets with single ticket number for each new ticket , the value increments by 1 example Ticket0001/2013-&gt; Ticket0002/2013. and during the change of year the value returns 0001 example Ticket000211/2013 -> Ticket00001/2014

Comment: You actually will disclose ticket frequency to users. I would use @unique. But pick any approaches above

Comment: Concur here. When users ask for sequential numbers they usually mean they want something unique that isn't impossible to refer to. People want to say "Did you you see ticket 83?" when referring to ticket 12499304083. If @Unique is too random for you, you could always use a time-stamp down to milli-seconds, appending the user's initials.

Answer (score 2):

Sequential numbering is always fun (/s) and something that comes up often in Notes/Domino.

There is a very well detailed Wiki article explaining the theory and use cases behind creating unique numbers.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/sequential-numbering.htm

and this article explaining Document locking while using unique numbering.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Employ_document_locking_to_assure_number_uniqueness